# How to resolve the Out of memory error in Azure for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, memory-management, out-of-memory, azure-aks

I am working in a project which is pulling a million of data from the database and that data is converted into a csv file for download. The database i am using is PostgreSQL and i am deploying it to AKS (Azure kubernetes). The code is working fine from my local. i am connecting the same database from the local which AKS is using. But when i am trying to execute the code in AKS i am always getting

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space] with root cause
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor.getExtractor(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.extract(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CustomLoader.java:412) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1044) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:995) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2887) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2869) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2701) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2696) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java
```

I am posting the code which is executed

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery);
List<Object[]> objectList = query.getResultList();
objectList.forEach(glObject -> {
 myEntity entity = myEntity.builder()
 .supl_num(glObject[0])
 .detail(glObject[1])
 ...............
  .build();
myEntityList.add(entity);   
});
```

the AKS deployment configurations

```
...........
ports:
     -containerPort: 80
resources:
  requests:
    cpu : 75m
    memory:256Mi
  limits:
     cpu:1
   memory: 2Gi
```

I don't understand why this is causing again and again

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe how to set that can you edit my code

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe using hibernate

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have updated my stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`defaultRowFetchSize`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters)  connection patameter in your JDBC URL so that the driver fetches the data in chunks rather than all at once.